# python callable class as a decorator naming convention

Tags: python

I have following decorator declared as callable object:

```
class nest:

    def __init__(self, func):

        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):

        self.obj = instance
        self.cls = owner

        return self.__call__

    def __call__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     ....
```

Then I can use it in the code like that:

```
class Abc:
    @nest
    def test(self, *args, **kwargs):
```

My question is: what is the convention of naming such decorator ? When I look into different decorators declaration (e.g. as functions) they're always? starting with lowercase. Nevertheless class name should start with the uppercase (according to PEP8). What is the correct pythonic way of naming decorator implemented as a class ?

Thank you in advance

Piotr

Comment: My opinion, name it as if it were a function (as you have). Most of the time, if not always, it will be used with decorator syntax, so that's less visually jarring. Keep in mind that PEP-8 is just a list of suggestions; only in the standard library are those suggestions mandatory.

Comment: If you really want it both ways, you can define the class in upper case, then say `nest = Nest` so you can use it in lower case.